# How to integrate CK-editor with angular 5. I am trying to integrate ck-editor v4 with application, i am getting 'Element Ref is not generic'

Tags: angular5, integration, ckeditor4.x

I tried integrating ck-editor version5, but so many options are not working. I tried with ck-editor version4, since there are more options but i got "**Element Ref is not generic**".

I am attaching reference code here....

installed ck-editor through npm
---->> npm install --save ckeditor4-angular

added module to my module
---->> import { CKEditorModule } from 'ckeditor4-angular';

My Code :: 
    {

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from 
    "@angular/common/http";
import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead';
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ckeditor4-angular';

@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [
  NgxDatatableModule, ModalModule.forRoot(),
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  FormsModule,
  TooltipModule.forRoot(),
  RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
   { useHash: true }
   ),
  CKEditorModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to question

Comment: Thanks for your response. Added module code, where i am including the ck-editor module after installing from npm.